# Unabled to create single view ios app in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to ios/xcode and I was trying to follow through the new [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views) tutorial. The first one has you create a ios single view app [image]. However when I go to xcode under the ios filter that, among others is not an option for me: [image] I have verified that my xcode is up to date via app store. Is this due to me not having a paid developer account? Are those templates in a beta channel of xcode?

Comment: That tutorial is showing Xcode 11... it has been replaced with “App” in Xcode 12

Comment: ah that makes sense. If you resubmit as answer I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering, as per the OP...

The tutorial in question was done using Xcode 11

In Xcode 12, there is no longer a Single View App option — it has been replaced with simply “App”

Answer (score 4):

Select app and then in the next screen select "Storyboard" in the "Interface" drop down menu. That will create what you need (mainly the Main.storyboard file) for the single view app. (see the linked screenshot here below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jhvI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayMBG.png)

Answer (score -2):

I don't think the "App" template that @donmag mentions is exactly the same (I don't believe it gives the same folder structure). I have a template on github for the Single View App that should match the folder structure you need, if you're still looking for that: https://github.com/jcross0204/ios-single-view-app-template/tree/master