# Can't find Single View Application on XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile

I just started learning Swift for school projects, I installed XCode 12 on the App Store but now on the tutorials I'm trying to follow they tell me to create a "Single View Application" but on the different templates I have there is no Single View Application.

I tried to chose other templates but when I do that I don't have the same files as the one in the tutorial.

I've tried to look on Internet about single view application for XCode 12 and Swift 5 but didn't find anything.

How can I create a Single View Application with this configuration ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Unabled to create single view ios app in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081136/unabled-to-create-single-view-ios-app-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No configuration to create Single View Application.

If you create app, this would be single view application only.

If you need you can embed `UINavigationController` or `UITabbarController` by select embed option in Editor.